# Spring 4 Switching from admin to admin/minor view causes resources not found

Tags: html, spring-4

The issue is that when I switch from admin to admin/minor causes resources not found.

Here is my controller :

package com.projc.spring.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class AdminController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(AdminController.class);

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request) {
        LOGGER.debug("Admin index page");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("admin/index");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin/minor" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView minor(HttpServletRequest request) {
        LOGGER.debug("index page");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("admin/minor");
        return model;
    }
}
```

in index.html I have menu with links :

```
<a href="admin"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label">Main view</span></a>

<a href="admin/minor"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label">Minor view</span> </a>
```

The first link works fine but I click on the second it loads the page but without css, js...since I have resources not found.

It's like /admin/minor is appended to /admin

For example a jquery file is referred by

```
http://localhost:8080/mintad/admin/admin/js/jquery-2.1.1.js
```

which has to be

```
http://localhost:8080/mintad/admin/js/jquery-2.1.1.js
```

I want to make a website for users and another one for adminitrator with respective urls : website_url and website_url/admin

I may do thing wrong. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use thymeleaf layout.It means use a template where I refer to each resource as **th:src** or **th:href**
Please check [Thymeleaf tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html) to see how.